# Send image in POST request python

Tags: python, image, post, python-requests

I'm trying to send a message with a picture to a certain website. (on the website, it looks like a regular chat with a seller.)

The request from the developer tools looks like this
[image]

I try to repeat it in my code, but I get a "400" response.

My code:
[image: make_request is simply a wrapper for requests.request(...)]
p.s.: make_request is just a wrapper for requests.request(...)

Any guesses as to what can be changed to get the site to accept my request?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. Turns out, it took turning on the brain and reading the "requests" documentation.
[image]

```
def send_photo_message(self, conversation_id, file_name='data\\photo.jpg', message='dws'):

    headers = self.refresh_token()

    image = open(file_name, "rb")

    url = f'https://gateway.kleinanzeigen.de/messagebox/api/users/130369537/conversations/{conversation_id}'

    params = {
        'warnPhoneNumber': 'true',
        'warnEmail': 'true',
        'warnBankDetails': 'true',
    }

    files = [
        ('attachment', (f'attachment-0-{time.time()}.jpg', image, 'image/jpeg')),
        ('message', ('blob', json.dumps({'message': message}), 'application/json'))
    ]

    response = self.make_request('post', url, headers=headers, params=params, files=files)

    image.close()

    pass

    return response
```